# Loading model on param route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've successfully build out my app to have a proper child route and it works as it should when the user navigates through the site, but on load straight to the show route (exhibitions/slug) ember data seems to break; however, I'm still getting the proper response from the API. Here is my code, hope it makes sense..

routes/exhibitions

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

const { set } = Ember;

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('exhibition');
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    set(controller, 'exhibitions', model);
  }
});
```

routes/exhibition

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { get, set } = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.queryRecord('exhibition', {
      'fields.slug': params.exhibition_slug
    });
  },
  serialize(model) {
    return { exhibition_slug: get(model, 'slug') };
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    set(controller, 'exhibition', model);
  }
});
```

model for exhibition

```
import Contentful from 'ember-data-contentful/models/contentful';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { belongsTo, hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Contentful.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  body: attr('string'),
  slug: attr('string')
});
```

router.js

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('homepage', { path: '/' });
  this.route('exhibitions');
  this.route('exhibition', { path: 'exhibitions/:exhibition_slug'});
});

export default Router;
```

Here is the JSON response (apologies for poor formatting)

```
{sys: {type: "Array"}, total: 1, skip: 0, limit: 1, items: [{,…}]}
items
:
[{,…}]
0
:
{,…}
fields
:
{title: "Hello", body: "This is the body.", slug: "hello"}
body
:
"This is the body."
slug
:
"hello"
title
:
"Hello"
sys
:
{space: {sys: {type: "Link", linkType: "Space", id: "kw98h7kialqf"}}, id: "5rllAHKFygCOma2wgy6WuI",…}
contentType
:
{sys: {type: "Link", linkType: "ContentType", id: "exhibition"}}
createdAt
:
"2018-02-20T15:48:08.093Z"
id
:
"5rllAHKFygCOma2wgy6WuI"
locale
:
"en-US"
revision
:
2
space
:
{sys: {type: "Link", linkType: "Space", id: "kw98h7kialqf"}}
type
:
"Entry"
updatedAt
:
"2018-02-20T15:52:19.063Z"
limit
:
1
skip
:
0
sys
:
{type: "Array"}
type
:
"Array"
total
:
1
```

The error I'm getting in the console is:

```
Error while processing route: exhibition Cannot read property 'Entry' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'Entry' of undefined
```

Let me know if anything else is needed!! Thank you!

Comment: The json response is not valid json. There are a lot of `,` missing! Where is that data from?

Comment: Hey Jeff, it's from Contentful, I think the lack of commas may have to do with how I copy and pasted it into StackOverflow.

Comment: JSON is definitely not valid. Maybe squash that first. Keys have to be in `"quotes" etc. So, your loading all of the exhibitions on the plural route... and the link-to's are getting you to the single route / and showing the model - but just refresh doesn't query?  Have you gotten it working with just ID's and findRecord or peekRecord?

Comment: @sheriffderek so yes, it worked with findRecord and ID. I was able to fix this by manually inserting the contentful Ember add-on's serializer. Not super clean as I think it's being imported twice now, but can deal with it..

Comment: I've haven't had much luck with the so-called "headless" CMSs yet. If Contentful turns out to be really really great... please make a note here. : )

Comment: @sheriffderek i'm really liking it right now. It deals with CMS data very differently than something like Wordpress, but I haven't hit many roadblocks...the backend GUI is definitely more geared towards those who kinda understand this stuff, it's not as dummy proof as a wordpress setup..

Comment: I'm not sure specifically about this addon - but you should be able to extend its serializer and just change the one thing - instead of duplicating it.